# How can I save workbench.xmi programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4, workbench

We have an RCP application, using Eclipse 3.x and we are migrating to Eclipse 4.

At a certain point in our application, we need to save the workbench.xml file with the contents of the perspectives. In Eclipse 3.x this was done by writing to the file using memento.

Is there any way in Eclipse 4 to save the workbench.xmi file with the perspectives content?

Apparently all the methods that existed in the Workbench class relating to saving perspectives have been removed and there are no others that do the same.

I tried to find where workbench.xmi is saved but without success.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The workbench.xmi contains just the current state of the application model, and is saved automatically when the RCP exits. The current state of the perspectives (and everything else) is saved.

Comment: Hello @greg-449, thanks for your reply. Yes, I know that when I close the application the perspectives are saved. But I need them saved into workbench.xmi without closing the application. This is what I need and I don't know how can I do.

Comment: I have added an answer on what to call, but I have never seen anything that needed to do this. Why do you think you need to save the model before the exit?

Comment: Because in our application there is the functionality to export/import perspectives. So before exporting I need to save the current state of the perspectives in the file.

Comment: For just a perspective you should look at this: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ModelPersistence/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IModelResourceHandler` to save the workbench.xmi

You can get this using `@Inject` or from the `IEclipseContext`.

Use the save method:

```
public void save() throws IOException
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your reply.